# change the date format in a grid field ExtJS

Tags: date, extjs, extjs4

simple question but I can't figure out how to resolve it.

I'm receiving a date with hour from JSON with this format :

```
"date_deb":"2013\/12\/28 23:00:00"
```

Note that the \ are for escaping the / and are not displayed.
I would like to display this dates in this format into my grid :

```
"28/12/2013 23:00:00"
```

I've tried this into my fields definition:

```
{name:'date_deb', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'd-m-Y H:i:s'}
```

But it's not working, nothing is displayed.
By checking the ExtJS docs, I've seen this :

```
dateReadFormat
```

I'm using ExtJS4.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your field definition provide the [`dateFormat`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-dateFormat) as it is returned from the server:

```
{name:'date_deb', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y/m/d H:i:s'}
```

and then in your column config use ExtJS's built-in [dateRenderer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-dateRenderer) with the format you'd like to render your dates with:

```
renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y H:i:s')
```

You'll only need [`dateReadFormat`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-dateReadFormat) and [`dateWriteFormat`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-dateWriteFormat) if you have a reader (to read data from server) **AND** a writer (to send modified data back to server) which need different date formats. Otherwise `dateFormat` will apply as the default format for both.

Answer (score 4):

If the above doesn't work for you, try adding xtype: 'datecolumn' in your grid's 'columns' config.

```
columns: [{
            text : 'date',
            dataIndex: 'LoginDateTime',
            xtype: 'datecolumn',
            format: 'Y-m-d g:i A',
}]
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

use this function to render date for grid

In your column definition define renderer as this

renderer: renderDate

example `{ dataIndex: 'TaskEndDate', header: 'PlannedEndDate', flex: 1, renderer: renderDate },`

```
function renderDate(value) 
{
    if (value == '' || value == undefined) {
        return '';
    }

    else {
        getDate = new Date(parseInt(value.substr(6)));
        }

   return Ext.util.Format.date(getDate, 'm-d-Y');
}
```

Comment: Works but the other solution is easier to set up :). But thanks for sharing your knwoledge :) !

Answer (score 1):

In your column config use "formatter".

```
    formatter: 'date("d/m/Y H:i:s")'
```